# CSS transition on background-color

Tags: css, css-transitions, background-color

I have a `div` with a background color and css transitions

```
#foo {
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 3000ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 3000ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 3000ms ease;
    transition: all 3000ms ease;
}
```

I also have a button. When the button is clicked, I would like to

1. immediately switch the `div` to transparent background and a final height
2. create a fade-in effect on `background-color` property only

To accomplish this, I've created some classes for the div

```
#foo.transparent {
    background-color:transparent; 
}

#foo.final {
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.9); 
    height:400px;
}
```

and apply them to the div with jQuery on click

```
$('#start').click(function() {
    $('#foo').addClass('transparent').addClass('final');
});
```

Unfortunately, height switches immediately to the final value (this is correct), but the background color doesn't perform the required transition from transparent to final value. What am I missing?
[**(fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/aqw4cbss/2/)

Comment: I am a bit lost. You are adding both classes on click at the same time and so I don't think your background is even changing. If you are looking to change it to transparent immediately and then slowly fade-in you may need to add a delay.

Comment: You are looking for something like this: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/aqw4cbss/7/)?

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier solution might be to use jQuery's `fadeIn()` effect, like this:

Html:

```
<button id="start">start animation</button>
<div id="foo">some content</div>
```

CSS:

```
#foo {
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.9);
}

#foo.final {
    height:400px
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#start').click(function() {
    console.log('click');
    $('#foo').addClass('final').hide().fadeIn();
});
```

And your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aqw4cbss/3/

Comment: This may be a solution, even if I preferred to use CSS transitions instead of jQuery. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

height is not animatiable. use `min-height` && `max-height` instead.
plus the backgrounds in your initial state and final state are the same, so how can it be transitioned from 2 equals state.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqw4cbss/5/)

Comment: This is why i first add the transparent class: my goal is to cause a transition from transparent to non transparent background

Answer (score -1):

I think you should look into JQuery `.animate` and `.css` functions.

```
$('#foo').css("opacity", "0");
$('#foo').animate({backgroundColor: "green"}, 500);
```

note: you should specify a default background-color and opacity in the css to transition from.

EDIT: You'll need the JQuery Color plugin in order to make this work (it's very small.) 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color